# Laravel 5.8 post call in curl works great but not with guzzle

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle

When I perform this post call in my terminal with curl everything works great I see the post call coming in:

my curl call:

```
curl -X POST https://requestloggerbin.herokuapp.com/bin/a4d73cbb-2ddc-4fc7-ac38-60c2fac7e015 -d '{"test": "foo"}'
```

I am trying to replicate this call in my laravel app with guzzle, but I don't see the post call coming in and I get no error messages whatsoever so I have no idea what's going wrong.

My guzzle call:

```
$client = new Client();

$request = $client->post(
    'https://requestloggerbin.herokuapp.com/bin/a4d73cbb-2ddc-4fc7-ac38-60c2fac7e015',
    ['body' => ['foo' => 'bar']]
);
$response = $request->send();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it is better to use the package for curl  . I use ixudra/curl package to handle the curl requests . It is easy to use

Comment: @farooq I need to use guzzle so I want to make this work

Comment: why you using `$response = $request->send();` . It is not required

Comment: @farooq I need to send the request no?

Answer (score 1):

`$response = $request->send();`

Which is not required at all .

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post('http://localhost.com/23', ['body' => $requestXmlBody]);

$result = $response->getBody()->getContents();

$result1 = simplexml_load_string($result);
```